# best way to store symfony configuration params in svn?

Tags: php, svn, symfony-1.4

What's the best way to work with configuration params (i.g. databases.yml, app.yml) in symfony 1.x in order to have different configurations for the staging and the prod server? 
For example, my staging project instance works with database STAGING and my prod project instance works with database PROD. Should I exclude databases.yml and app.yml from the svn repo and configure manually each instance of my project? Should I include in the repo the prod values? or maybe the staging ones?

Answer (score 0):

It kind of depends on how "secure" you consider your SVN-repository...

If it's very secure, and you're the only developer, I would go for one `databases.yml` and one `app.yml`  and configure the different environments there. So something like:

```
prod:
  doctrine:
     ...use database PRODUCTION ...
staging:
  doctrine:
     ...use database STAGING ...
dev:
  doctrine:
     ...use database DEV ...
```

Works "out of the box", and keeps data versioned as well. (Also updates to the app.yml are versioned, and in your development version you can already prepare a configuration change for production).

In a less "secure" repository, I would go for ignoring the `databases.yml` and `app.yml`  in the version control, and then writing these for each environment when you set it up. You could also include a versioned `databases.yml.dist` and `app.yml.dist` with predefined settings...

Comment: Thanks! But what if I want both the symfony dev and prod environment in my staging instance?

Comment: Then I guess your mis-using the symfony environments. You could either create two staging environments `staging-dev` and `staging-prod`. Or go for the ignored files and `*.yml.dist` setup...

Comment: Sorry, but I think I'm not mis-using the environments.
Quoting from the symfony documentation:

Don't mix up the notions of environment and server. In symfony, different environments are different configurations, and correspond to a front controller (the script that executes the request). Different servers correspond to different domain names in the URL.

[...]
For instance, you can run in the production environment even on your development server
This means that many environments are available on each server.

Comment: I stand corrected :-) (And I admit I frequently switch to  my own `production` and `cache` environment to test certain settings. But I tought I was misusing it myself too)...
But, in that case, I would go for the ignored files...